# How to forge Received header when sending from Mac Mail?

Tags: email, macos, gmail

When I use Mac Mail to send a message, it has a received header included in it. Even though I'm running my SMTP through a remote server, my IP shows up (where it's 123.123.123.123).

Received: from [123.123.123.123] (host.of.my.ssh.tunnel.com [x.x.x.x])

I've seen many messages where it says:

Received: from my.own.domain.com (host.of.my.ssh.tunnel.com [x.x.x.x])

Is there any way to change [123.123.123.123] to my.own.domain.com in Mac Mail?

Comment: Not in Mail.app, no. It's picking up the IP from the OS, and I'm guessing (hence not a proper answer below) that this is to do with name resolution.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving aside my concerns about why you want to hide this data, it's not your Mac Mail program that's inserting this data, it's the remote mail server, so unless you control that server and what data it puts into the headers, you're out of luck.

If you really need to send mail anonymously, and don't control the target mail server in this case, you could use an anonymous relay service, like the variety which come with many domain registrar's whois privacy products.

Comment: The thing here is that I'm routing all my through my VPS, and on some computers I have my IP as 192.168.x.x, while my actual IP on some other computer. From that, I'm pretty sure it's possible to change it to a domain, as I've done it myself. I've dealt with all 3 situations with the same account.

Comment: Ahh, got it, what you're concerned about is the name given during HELO/EHLO by Mac Mail.  You're probably out of luck with this one, but you might play around with /etc/hosts to see if you can convince Mac Mail that your default interface has a valid host name.